# refresh all divs in a php page using Ajax

Tags: php, html, refresh

I have a php page with 9 different divs, These divs are updated after every page reload from mysql database. I want to do it automatically with out whole page refresh. Is it possible? I know this can be done by Ajax, but I don't understand how I do it. Can anyone please let me know the good tutorial on that?

Comment: Do you know http://google.com ? Type the headline of your question into the google search field

Comment: @hek2mgl if you know, why don't you provide him a link?

Comment: Give a man a fish and he will eat one day,... :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for your suggestion, but I did it before with no luck.

Comment: @Aemz Tell me what you exactly not understood and I'll help. Please post some code or tutorials that have you already tried. Btw I've not downvoted the post

Comment: @hek2mgl +1 for the quote. good one. perfect timing :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  // call your function here
  // make tha ajax call here to update the divs
  // this function will run every 5 secs and will make the AJAX call
  // write the function here to update the divs
}, 5000);
```

Read below

[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)

[Update whole page on Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941933/update-whole-page-on-ajax-request)

[Ajax update on div with a id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815596/ajax-update-on-div-with-a-id)

If you don't want to update the page constantly, just make the AJAX calls which update the divs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple and effective way to do this with jQuery:

Overview:
On the script you direct your ajax call to, have it query the database and  echo out the updated HTML you want to replace within the div tags and then it's as simple as replacing the div html with the returned html in the anonymous function inside the success param:

Your Ajax call in your Javascript file

```
//wrap up your data in a GET style string seperated by ampersands (&)
var dataString = foo=1234&bar=12345

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajax.php,
  data: dataString,
  success: function(html) {
    $("#refresh_div").html(html);
},
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Then in your 'ajax.php' you access the variables you just sent to the PHP script via the $_POST superglobal

```
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
$bar = $_POST['bar']

$mysqli= new mysqli($params);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$foo);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

echo $result
```

All of the text/html that is echoes out will be passed back to the ajax success param as the html var and then you can replace the divs contents with jquery.

hope this helps.